# What is the Excel Formula to calculate based on consumption and rate

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I need help to come out with a solution for this:

Actually I want to calculate my electricity consumption. as the attached pic. the first consumption 0-200kwh, rate $0.218, for 201-300 consumption rate is $0.334, 301-600 rate is $0.516, 601-900 rate is $0.546.

I tried using :

```
=IF(F3<200, 0.218, IF(F3>200, 0.334, IF(F3>300, 0.516, IF(F3>600, 0.546, 0))))*F3
```

but get the wrong answer.

I also tried:

```
=VLOOKUP(F3, [Book2.xlsx]Sheet3!$A$2:$C$603, 3, 0)
```

but what I got are the total consumption(refer pic it sum up to 326kwhx0.516 =168.216).

I want to separate the kwh for the first 0-200, 201-300 and so on according to respective rate. How can I do that?

[image]

[image: Sample]

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried and why it's not working.  We can't guess what needs to be done given only what you have so far.

Comment: And what you actually need to calculate - cost?  I'd also add typing in all caps is considered internet impolite

Comment: Hi, sorry for the caps, no intention to impolite.huhuu

Comment: actually i want to calculate my electricity consumption.  as the attached pic.  the first consumption 0-200kwh, rate $0.218, for 201-300 consumption rate is $0.334, 301-600 rate is $0.516, 601-900 rate is $0.546.

Comment: i tried using : =IF(F3<200,0.218,IF(F3>200,0.334,IF(F3>300,0.516,IF(F3>600,0.546,0))))*F3     but get the wrong answer.. i'm not good in excel, but i tried, really need your help..

Comment: edit the question and put the clarification there, into the question, not into the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track but you need to turn a few things around. Your formula:

```
=IF(F3<200,0.218,IF(F3>200,0.334,IF(F3>300,0.516,IF(F3>600,0.546,0))))*F3
```

Play it through for the value 350. You'll never get past the `IF(F3>200` because 350 is greater than 200 and the rest of the formula won't be evaluated. So, change the comparison order from big number to small number.

```
=IF(F3<200,0.218,IF(F3>600,0.334,IF(F3>300,0.516,IF(F3>200,0.334,0))))*F3
```

As an alternative to nested IF() you may want to consider a lookup table sorted by the consumption threshold values. Use Vlookup with TRUE or 1 as the fourth parameter for an approximate lookup, which returns the result that is equal to or smaller than the lookup value.

[image]

Comment: before this i have tried the vlookup but im not good maybe keep i tryin again. Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer as shown in the [Tour](http://superuser.com/tour)